# I'll have him call you vs I'll get him to call you

Tags: causatives, causative-have, causative-get

I understand that to have somebody do something for me means I ask them or command them to do that.
Is there a slight difference in the meaning if "I get them to do something"? Is there a difference if I omit the "to" as in "to get somebody do something"?

Comment: @MichaelWokeHarvey: I don't think I believe that. Do you have any supporting evidence?

Comment: ...hmm. Apparently, the "prevalence" value in Google Books for [***I'll have you know***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%27ll+have+you+know&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20%27ll%20have%20you%20know%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2CI%20'll%20have%20you%20know%3B%2Cc0) is 0.000018% for AmE, and [0.000022% for BrE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%27ll+have+you+know&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20%27ll%20have%20you%20know%3B%2Cc0) (where bigger number = "less common", as in "per so-many words").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'll have him call you.

suggests that the speaker is i a position to give orders to "him". In contrast

> I'll get him to call you.

might suggest more persuasion than an order, but this difference is a subtle one.

I am not sure what "to" you are thinking of omitting. The first sentence "I'll have him call you." does not include a "to" and none has been omitted. The second includes a "to" and it may not validly be left out.